# Set Background color: Opposite of -transparent

Tags: imagemagick

Say I have a PNG with transparent pixels, how could I translate them to a solid color?

*(Note this is slightly different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background) as I'm looking to replace with an arbitrary color. White is "special" in ImageMagick, as the accepted answer there indicates by the fact it omits to mention white).*

Comment: Just so you know, the imagemagick command has excellent help via this flag: `convert --help`.

Comment: @halfer It's voluminous, to be sure: convert --help has 293 lines.  Whether or not it is excellent depends largely upon how well tutored someone is in image magick's grammar and idioms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace transparency in PNG images with white background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For me, the following works (ImageMagick 6.6.3-1):

```
convert in.png -background "#FF0000" -flatten out.png
```

Just swap the red color to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: `-flatten` was the key for me.  Otherwise the image seemed unchanged.

Comment: How can this be extended to animated GIFs? As @MatthewLeingang mentions, omitting `-flatten` seems to have no effect (background still transparent). Adding `-flatten` flattens the entire series of images, i.e., there is no animation any more.