# ImageMagick, replace semi-transparent white with opaque white

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, transparency, imagemagick-convert

I have an icon with a fully transparent background and a semi-transparent, white foreground. I would like to make the foreground fully opaque, can this be achieved with ImageMagick?

I have tried juggling different combinations of these;

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12619

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18196

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16718

, but cannot produce the desired result. Any tips?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier if you posted your icon, but my testing shows that this works for what I think you have:

```
convert icon.png -channel A -threshold 75% output.png
```

The above is somewhat coarse as it makes *all* partially transparent pixels fully opaque. If you wanted to be a bit more *surgical*, you could only set the opacity to fully opaque when the Red, Green and Blue pixels are greater than 90% and the original opacity (alpha) is between 40%-60% like this:

```
convert icon.png -channel A \
   -fx "(r>0.9 && g>0.9 && b>0.9 && a>0.4 && a<0.6) ? 1.0 : a" output.png
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the '-fx' thing is exactly what i needed for applying updated alpha channel only for opaque pixels. thanks a lot!