# Imagemagick: replace alpha pixel with color-shade pixel

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, transparency, imagemagick-convert

In [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937084/imagemagick-remove-alpha-component-replace-all-intermediate-alpha-pixel-with-s) I made false assumption
that I need to remove pixels with alpha,
but I actually need to use alpha percentage as shade of white.

Because just removing alpha-pixel changes lines.
But as background is to be white.

Image btn_bg_common_press.9.png

[image: btn_bg_common_press.9.png]

[image]

becomes

[image: became]

I also looked at [ImageMagick, replace semi-transparent white with opaque white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692694/imagemagick-replace-semi-transparent-white-with-opaque-white) and found that I can do with

```
convert icon.png -channel A -fx "(a>0.5) ? 1.0 : 0" output.png
```

Though that is still rough.