# Android Gradle build Error:Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red

Tags: android, android-studio, png, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

While trying to solve [an Android Gradle build Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469807/automatically-solve-android-build-errorframe-pixels-must-be-either-solid-or-tra?noredirect=1#comment46133327_28469807) using a [ImageMagick conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939645/imagemagick-replace-alpha-pixel)

I ran into a new Android error:

> Error:Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red.
>
> Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\sdk-Android-Studio\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

What does it mean, and how do I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

When you make a .9 picture, you should let it be nice. It means the picture is a standard .9 (PNG) picture, so check the resources.