# Removing Transparency using Imagemagick.NET

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick.net

A part of a software package I've written takes in a binary encoded PDF, converts it to a Bitmap, and saves it to a blob in a db.  I'm discovering that although it's not immediately visible in the original in it's PDF form, there is transparency in the document that is completely visible in the converted bitmap.

I've seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background) where the command line version of imagemagick can "flatten" an image to remove the transparency layers.  Can this somehow be done with the .NET package?  How do I remove the transparency before saving the bitmap?  I need to keep it as a bitmap as it's a universally recognized format for their label printers.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Write image data from a pdf file to a bitmap file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgData"></param>
    private static void convertPdfToBmp(ImageData imgData)
    {
        MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        // Settings the density to 600 dpi will create an image with a better quality
        settings.Density = new Density(600);

        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            // Add all the pages of the pdf file to the collection
            images.Read(imgData.pdfFilePath, settings);

            // Create new image that appends all the pages horizontally
            using (IMagickImage image = images.AppendVertically())
            {
                // Convert the image to a bitmap
                image.Format = MagickFormat.Bmp;

                // Delete any old file 
                if (File.Exists(imgData.bmpFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(imgData.bmpFilePath);
                }
                // Save result as a bmp
                image.Write(imgData.bmpFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use different methods of adjusting the transparency layers, or coloring of the background without success.

```
            //image.BackgroundColor = new ColorMono(false);
            //image.TransparentChroma(new MagickColor(0, 0, 0), new MagickColor(0, 0, 0));
            //image.TransparentChroma(new ColorRGB(0, 0, 0), new ColorRGB(65535, 65535, 65535));
            //image.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor("#fff");
            //image.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor("#ffffff");
            //image.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor("#ffffffffffff");
            //image.Settings.BackgroundColor.A = 0;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try removing the Alpha component, and set the background color depending on the output:

```
image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Remove);
```

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Changing the background color isn't working though.  What am I missing there?

Comment: try image.Settings.BackgroundColor

Comment: I did, that's one of the things listed in the OP.  Just tried it again for good measure. `image.Settings.BackgroundColor.R = 65535` and I still see white.

Comment: To elaborate, I am just trying to always force a white background.

Comment: image.Settings.BackgroundColor = Color.White

Comment: `image.Settings.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;` has no affect on the output image.  (I'm using `Color.Black` to check)

Comment: The removing of alpha behind the scenes is using the background color to determine "transparency" which is probably what you are seeing - try setting ALL background color values at the same time (including the ones above) to see what you need to do

Comment: I notice that `Color.Black` colors the A channel of ARGB.  I'll play around with it some more.