# Applying color to a PDF Conversion in ImageMagick.NET

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick.net

In continuation from a previous SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093839/removing-transparency-using-imagemagick-net) I've gone from being able to remove the transparency from a PDF conversion, to not being able to adjust the background color of the conversion.  I've tried everything that I can find on the [Imagemagick.NET github docs](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/Documentation).  I need to ensure that ANY image that is passed through this software package has a non transparent white background.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Write image data from a pdf file to a bitmap file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgData"></param>
    private static void convertPdfToBmp(ImageData imgData)
    {
        MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        // Settings the density to 600 dpi will create an image with a better quality
        settings.Density = new Density(600);

        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            // Add all the pages of the pdf file to the collection
            images.Read(imgData.pdfFilePath, settings);

            // Create new image that appends all the pages horizontally
            using (IMagickImage image = images.AppendVertically())
            {
                // Remove the transparency layers and color the background white
                image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Remove);

                int aval = image.Settings.BackgroundColor.A = 0;
                int rval = image.Settings.BackgroundColor.R = 0;
                int bval = image.Settings.BackgroundColor.G = 0;
                int gval = image.Settings.BackgroundColor.B = 0;

                // Convert the image to a bitmap
                image.Format = MagickFormat.Bmp;

                // Delete any old file 
                if (File.Exists(imgData.bmpFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(imgData.bmpFilePath);
                }
                // Save result as a bmp
                image.Write(imgData.bmpFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code above, if I set any of the 4 channels `image.Settings.BackgroundColor` to a different color, it has no affect on the image.  If I use `image.BackgroundColor` it has no affect on the image.  What am I missing?

Note: in the above code I am setting the colors to black to verify the code is working.  I've tried other colors as well for giggles.

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings from:

```
settings.Density = new Density(600);
```

to,

```
settings.Density = new Density(600);
settings.ColorType = ColorType.TrueColor;
settings.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor(Color.White);
```

I have already tried this and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when converting a PDF file to a set of images.
For me, what resolved was not to use the settings object (except for density) and apply the desired properties (Format, BackgroundColor, ColorType) to the images, instead.

```
magickReadSettings = new MagickReadSettings();
magickReadSettings.Density = new Density(300);

using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    // Add all the pages of the pdf file to the collection
    await images.ReadAsync(pdf, magickReadSettings);

    foreach (IMagickImage<ushort> image in images)
    {
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
        image.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor(255, 255, 255, 255);
        image.ColorType = ColorType.Grayscale;
    }
}
```